# Adjust number of digits displayed for timer property?

Tags: scripting, game-engine, properties

I want to make a nice timer in Blender Game. I used a timer property, but it doesn't look right because it has way too much digits. I only want it to show the number of seconds and 2 decimal digits.

I checked the source code of the property but I'm not sure what to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option with quite a few Logic Bricks, but

**formatting.py:**

```
def propertyToText(controller):    
    sensor = controller.sensors[0]
    propertyName = sensor.propName
    owner = controller.owner
    value = owner[propertyName]

    formattedValue = "{:.2f}".format(value)

    owner.text = formattedValue
```

Usage:
Have a Property (e.g. timer)

Property Sensor [enable True Level Triggering] 
Mode:Changed Property: your property

--> Python Controller Module:formatting.propertyToText